# What is wrong with this design? Overriding or overloading of java.util.HashMap

Tags: java, programming-languages, collections

This question was asked to me in MS interview.  I wanna know the exact design issue in this piece of code.  Code was already given, needed to find the design issue.

I have class MyHashMap which extends java HashMap class. In MyHashMap class I have to keep some information of employees. Key in this map will be  firstName+lastName+Address  .

```
public MyHashMap extends HashMap<Object, Object> {
  //some member variables 
  //
  public void put(String firstName, String lastName, String Address, Object obj) {
       String key =   firstName + lastName+ Address;
       put(key, obj);
  }

  public Object get(String firstName, String lastName, String Address) {
       String key =   firstName + lastName+ Address;
       return get(key);
  }

  public void remove(Strig key) {
        put(key, ""); 
  }

  //some more methods 
}
```

What is wrong with this design?  Should I subclass HashMap or should I declare 
HashMap as member variable of this class? Or should I have implemented hashCode/equals methods?

Comment: Is having the Map interface a requirement, or is that your take on the question?

Comment: Was it stated that the key should be a concatenation of firstName + lastName + Address? To me, an additional POJO combining these properties and implementing equals() and hashCode() seems a much better solution.

Comment: Code was already given I have to find out issues with the design, if any

Comment: This is from an "MS interview"?  Why wasn't Microsoft asking you about .NET instead of Java? :)

Comment: Looks more as homework to me, to be honest. This clashes with good design so horribly that I can't envision someone could write this and not be ashamed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are quite a few problems, but the biggest problem I can see it that you're using a concatenated `String` as a key.  The following two calls are different, but equivalent:

```
final MyHashMap map = new MyHashMap();

map.put("foo", "", "baz", new Object());
map.put("", "foo", "baz", new Object()); // Overwrites the previous call
```

There's also an issue that you're declaring that the key type as an `Object`, but always using `String` and are therefore not taking advantage of the type safety that comes with generics.  For example, if you wanted to loop through the `keySet` of your `Map`, you'd have to cast each `Set` entry to a `String`, but you couldn't be sure that someone didn't abuse you `Map` by using an `Integer` key, for example.

Personally, I would **favour composition over inheritance** unless you have a good reason not to.  In your case, `MyHashMap` is **overloading** the standard `Map` methods of `put`, `get` and `remove`, but **not overriding** any of them.  You should inherit from a class in order to change its behaviour, but your implementation does not do this, so composition is a clear choice.

To act as an example, overloading rather than overriding means that if you make the following declaration:

```
Map<Object, Object> map = new MyHashMap();
```

**none** of your declared methods will be available.  As recommended by some of the other answers, it would be far better to use an object composed of firstName, lastName and address to act as your map key, but you must remember to implement `equals` and `hashCode`, otherwise your values will not be retrievable from the `HashMap`.

Answer (score 5):

What's wrong with that design is primarily that is claims to be a `HashMap<Oject, Object>`, but isn't really. The overloaded methods "replace" the `Map` methods, but those are still accessible - now you're supposed to use the class in a way that is incompatible with the `Map` interface and ignore the (still technically possible) compatible way to use it.

The best way to do this would be to make an `EmployeeData` class with name and address fields and `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods based on those (or, better yet, a unique ID field). Then you don't need a non-standard Map subclass - you can simply use a `HashMap<EmployeeData, Object>`. Actually, the value type should be more specific than `Object` as well.

Comment: +1: The Liskov Substitution Principle should be followed in any OO language.

Answer (score 4):

I would go for declaring HashMap as member variable of your class.

I don't remember if a great explanation is given in Clean Code or Effective Java, but basically, it's simplier to do, requires less work if the API changes.

generally, extending such a class means you want to change its behavior.

Comment: Same.. i would prefer aggregation over sublcassing

Answer (score 3):

My first take would be that:

```
public MyHashMap extends HashMap<Oject, Object>
```

is wrong. No type safety.

If a Map is **required** then at least make it

```
public MyHashMap extends HashMap<NameAddress, Employee>
```

and adjust the put and get the same. A NameAddress use firstname, lastname and address
in the equals and hashCode.

I personally feel that a Set interface would match better, with possibly a HashMap as a member. Then you could define the interface like it should be:

```
public EmployeeSet implements Set<Employee> {
  private static class NameAddress {
    public boolean equals();
    public int hashCode();
  } 

  private HashMap employees = new HashMap<NameAddress, Employee>();   

  public add(Employee emp) {
    NameAddress nad = new NameAddress(emp);
    empoyees.add(nad, emp);
  }

  public remove(Employee emp) {
  }
}
```

and extract name and address info within the implementation to create the key.

**EDIT** David pointed out that NameAddress doesn't need to be Comparable and I removed that part of the interface. Added hashCode for correctness.

Comment: Why make NameAddress comparable?  HashMap doesn't implement SortedMap.

Answer (score 3):

The map uses an internal key based on first name, last name and address. So the `remove` method should (1) be implemented as `remove(String firstName, String lastName, String Address)` and (2) it should not change the behaviour of the original remove method (which really deleted the entry) by just changing the value. A better implementation of remove would be:

```
public void remove(String firstName, String lastName, String address) {
   String key =   firstName + lastName + address;
   return remove(key);
}
```

Comment: 2) It doesn't change the behaviour of the original remove method, because it doesn't override it.

Comment: Sure - but the question asked for bad design. And it is pretty bad to use the 'remove' method name for something completely different (this remove method doesn't remove anything).

Answer (score 2):

Two other "heinous crimes" against good practice are that the `remove` method:

- overloads `Map.remove(<K>)` rather than overriding it (so you have a leaky abstraction), and
- implements a behavior that is incompatible with the behavior of the method it overrides!

Setting the value associated with a key to an empty string is NOT THE SAME as removing the entry for the key.  (Even setting it to `null` is subtly different ...)

This is not a violation of the Liskov substitutability principle, but it could be really confusing for someone trying to use the type.  (Depending on whether you called the method via the `Map` type or the `MyHashMap` type you could end up using different methods with different semantics ....)

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends a lot on the context and what they exactly asked. For example, is a highly concurrent context, you should have used Hashtable instead. Also, you should specify the types (String, Object) instead of (Object,Object) to get compiler support on the keys.

I think a better design would have been to implement the Map interface and keep the HashMap/HashTable as an internal parameter of the object.